# How to make a scrollbar in jQuery.Marquee plugin always fill the screen size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, marquee

I am using the **[jQuery.Marquee](https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee)** plugin to create a scrolling effect on my website. I need the scroll bar associated with the content in the selection area to always match the screen size, regardless of the length of the content.

For example, if the content is large (pictures), the scroll bar scrolls the full width of the screen on all screens, but when the content becomes small (pictures), the scroll bar on large screens does not fill the full width of the screen

Here are my plugin settings that I use

```
$('.marquee').marquee({
   //duration in milliseconds of the marquee
   duration: 13000,
   //gap in pixels between the tickers
   gap: 24,
   //time in milliseconds before the marquee will start animating
   delayBeforeStart: 0,
   //'left' or 'right'
   direction: 'left',
   //true or false - should the marquee be duplicated to show an effect of continues flow
   duplicated: true,
});
```

Is there a native way or a workaround?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!